# jquery isotope how to achieve nested filtering

Tags: jquery, nested, jquery-isotope

can anyone point me in the right direction, on how nested filtering is achieved in isotope? I'm trying to replicate the methods used here - http://voky.com.ua/frittata/dark.html in particular when blog or portfolio are clicked, then they in turn filter more items. How is that achieved with isotope?

Many thanks.

Comment: +1 for that link. Great looking site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smoke and mirrors... It is not really using "nested" filters.

He is extracting the `id` parameter from the hash and creating a filter like `.sectionname{id}` instead of the top level ones which are just `.sectioname`. Basically it is not nested, just uses a "lot" of filters.

```
else if( page == 'portfolio' )
{
     filter = '.item-portfolio';
     if( id )
     {
        filter = '#item-portfolio' + id;
        elem = $(filter);
        console.log(elem);
        if( elem.prevAll('.item-portfolio-details').length )
        {
            id = elem.prevAll('.item-portfolio-details').eq(0).attr('id');
            $('#item-next').attr('href', '#page=portfolio&id=' + id.substr(14));
            filter += ', #item-next';
        }
        if( elem.nextAll('.item-portfolio-details').length )
        {
            id = elem.nextAll('.item-portfolio-details').eq(0).attr('id');
            $('#item-prev').attr('href', '#page=portfolio&id=' + id.substr(14));
            filter += ', #item-prev';
        }
        filter += ', #item-back-portfolio';
     }
}
```

The rest of the code shown is working out whether to include the next and previous buttons (and appending additional filter values if they are needed). Very cool site.